# Get bucket objects based on upload date from S3 bucket through Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get the list of objects which are older than 90 days form s3 bucket through ansible. My query is where and how can i insert the condition in the playbook .

- name: List all objects in specific bucket
  aws_s3:
  encrypt: yes
  aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
  aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
  mode: list
  bucket: "{{ bucket }}"
  prefix: "{{ database_name }}/"
  marker: "{{ database_name }}/"
  s3_url: "{{ s3_url }}"
  validate_certs: no
  when:

Comment: Hi Ravi Shankar welcome to SO. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70172250/edit) and fix the formatting. The edit page has illustrative help on how to make your code snippet legible. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to filter objects in that manner. I don't just mean "not possible using `aws_s3:`," I mean it is not possible via the [AWS S3 `ListObjectsV2` API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) and thus ansible cannot do that, either

Unfortunately, you would need to page through *all* objects and look at their `last_modified` attribute in order to filter them "client side." I have pretty healthy suspicions that `aws_s3:` is not even designed with such monstrous pagination cases in mind, but perhaps with diligent use of `marker:` you could get them all

You may have some success looking in CloudTrail for `PutObject` operations, if you have CloudTrail turned on, but the S3 API is not designed to solve your stated use case